# How to delete user on strapi v4 with GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, strapi, graphql-playground

I don't know why but everytime I can't delete any user on graphQL playground, its always forbidden access. I checked "destroy" on setting >> role >> userpermission and put koen bearer but still didn't work,
Here is what my code on playground,

```
mutation deleteUser {
deleteUsersPermissionsUser(id: "118") {
data {
  id
  attributes {
    username
    email
   }
  }
 }
}
```

here is the response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Forbidden access",
      "extensions": {
        "error": {
          "name": "ForbiddenError",
          "message": "Forbidden access",
          "details": {}
        },
        "code": "FORBIDDEN"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Comment: Hi Hardy! I think you need to be abit more precise in describing your problem. In the User & Permissions Plugin --> Roles you have normally at least : Authenticated and Public. When you use the Authenticated Role you will need to make sure the created API-Token has Full-Access Permission set instead of Read-Only.